# What is this cooking utensil labeled "Orka by Mastrad" and "1 ml = 1 pinch"?

Tags: utensils

It is labeled "Orka by Mastrad".  It also says "1 ml = 1 pinch" on the right-side part.  What is this object and what is it used for?

[image: thingy]

Answer (score 25):

This is a single salad tong, as seen [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001RCTNB2)

Notice the way the two tongs connect at the handle, and how the nearer one has the same shape as the poster's image.

[image: Salad tongs]

Comment: Well done! Kudos.

Comment: The black ones are on Amazon too: https://smile.amazon.com/Mastrad-A17200-Salad-Tongs-Black/dp/B001RCTN9O?sa-no-redirect=1

Comment: @Jefromi The black ones are too expensive, compared to the green ones.